# What does =~ m/\#F/ mean in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

```
open DMLOG, "<dmlog.txt" or &error("Can't open log file: $!");
chomp(@entirelog=<DMLOG>);
 close DMLOG;
 for $line (@entirelog) 
{

if ($line =~ m/\#F/)
    {
    $titlecolumn = $line;
    last;
     }
 }
```

I found that =~ is a regular expression I think, but I don't quite understand what its doing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you understand what *regular expressions* are? Or, is the `=~` throwing you off?

In most programming languages, you would see something like this:

```
 if ( regexp(line, "/#F/") ) {
   ...
}
```

However, in Perl, regular expressions are inspired by Awk's syntax. Thus:

```
if ( $line =~ /#F/ ) {
   ...
}
```

The `=~` means the regular expression will act upon the variable name on the left. If the pattern `#F` is found in `$line`, the `if` statement is true.

You might want to look at the [Regular Expression Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) if you're not familiar with them. Regular expressions are extremely powerful and very commonly used in Perl. In fact, they tend to be very used in Perl and is one of the reasons developers in other languages will claim that Perl is a *Write Only* language.

Answer (score 6):

It assigns the first line to `$titlecolumn` that contains an `#` followed by an `F`.

The `=~` is the *bind operator* and applies a regex to a string. That regex would usually be written as `/#F/`. The `m` prefix can be used to emphasize that the following literal is a prefix (important when other delimiters are used).

Answer (score 3):

It is called [Binding Operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators). It is used to match pattern on RHS with the variable on LHS. Similarly you have got `!~` which negates the matching.

For your particular case:

```
$line =~ m/\#F/
```

This test whether the `$line` matches the pattern - `/#F/`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `=~` is the binding operator binding an expression to the pattern match `m//`.

The `if` statement checks, if a line matches the given regular expression. In this case, it checks, if there is a hash-sign followed by a capital F.

The backslash has just been added (maybe) to avoid treating `#` as a comment sign (which isn't needed).

Comment: `=~` has nothing to do with regular expressions. It's a means of telling m//, s/// and tr/// on which variable they should operate.

Comment: `\ ` is not needed here. `\#` and `#` will be treated identically since the `x` modifier isn't used.

Comment: @ikegami your 1st comment should be an answer for +10. You told more understandable what the `=~` does as the above cited doc about the binding operator. Really nice comment. +10 if I could :)